# Spring-Hibernate Commit Transaction After Page Submit

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Hibernate
Using @Transactional Annotation.

My MVC Layer are Controller, Model, Service and DAO

My Requirement is that When i Open my page, i want to save the data into DabaBase using DB Procedure but not to commit,
I want to put that data on Hold.

and when that page open i want to do some Calculation, and when user hit Submit button, I want to commit that hold data..
But using @Transaction it is not possibile so commit data of Previous Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long running transactions come with big problems. I would recommend finding an alternative approach:

1. User opens a spring controller URL
2. Put your data in a special table/tables that store this transitional data
3. On submit, get the data from the tables in #2, use it and delete

Using a transaction that spans across 2 user requests has obvious issues. What happens if the user closes the browser/loses network after the 1st request. You have uncommitted data with possible row/table level locks which may bring down your app.

If you still think you want to use the long running transaction, 1 possible approach would be:

1. You need to use progrmmatic transaction management. Access the hibernate session directly (not through annotations)
2. Store the hibernate session object in http sesssion on first request
3. On second request commit the session and close it and remove from http session.
4. Have a http session listener which on session destroyed checks for hibernate session object and closes it.
5. Have a transaction timeout `session.getTransaction().setTimeout()` so that in case the user does not respond in say 30s, your transaction will still end unlocking the underlying db resources

Comment: Thanks For Suggestion, Sir, if i follow 2nd Approach, then i need to store Hibernate Session Object in Http-session or Transaction Object..?. Also Sir, Spring DAO Layer is Singleton, So if that Transaction Object is not Commit, will it affect Other Transaction..?

Comment: Yes you need to store hibernate session in http session. Singleton is not an issue, however an uncommitted long running transaction will cause isssues at some point - so avoid using this approach.

Comment: Hi Sir How to Create Manual transaction management in Spring-Hibernate..?